# r markdown output to pdf: stop plot breaking up a code chunk

Tags: r, pdf, plot, r-markdown

I am printing an r markdown file to pdf. I've tried various output specifications, but the plot keeps displaying in the middle of segments [1] and [2].

I want the all of the code to be displayed one chunk, and will call the plot later in the document.

````
```{r, include=TRUE, results='hide'}
# [1] There is code up here

# [plot interrupts the code chunk here] Scatter plot

plot1 = plot(df$var1, df$var)

# [2] More code below this point
```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the chunk option `fig.show = 'hold'` to display all the plots produced by a chunk at the end of the chunk.  Here is an example .Rmd file and output.

````
---
title: Stop Plot Breakikng Up Code Chunk
output: pdf_document
---

The key is to use the chunk option `fig.show = 'hold'` so that all plots from
the chunk will will displayed at the end of the chunk.

```{r setup, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.show = "hold")
```

We'll use the `mtcars` data set for the example.

```{r plot1, include = TRUE, results = "hide"}
mean(mtcars$wt)
mean(mtcars$mpg)

plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)

var(mtcars$wt)
```

End of example.
````

[image]

### EDIT:

Another solution, closer to what I think you are looking for, is to use `ref.label` to reuse code chunks.

````
---
title: Stop Plot Breaking Up Code Chunk
output: pdf_document
---

The key is to use the chunk option `fig.show = 'hold'` so that all plots from
the chunk will will displayed at the end of the chunk.

```{r setup, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.show = "hold",
               collapse = TRUE)
```

We will use the `mtcars` data set for the example.

```{r all_code}
```{r mean_code, ref.label = "means", echo = TRUE, results = "hide"}
```{r plot1_code, ref.label = "plot1", echo = TRUE, fig.show = "hide", fig.keep = "none"}
```{r var_code, ref.label = "var_wt", echo = TRUE, results = "hide"}
```


Description of a plot

```{r "plot1", echo = FALSE}
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
```

More text.

Below here, chunks that are evaluated, but not shown.

```{r means, include = FALSE}
mean(mtcars$wt)
mean(mtcars$mpg)
```

```{r var_wt, include = FALSE}
var(mtcars$wt)
```

End of the example.
````

[image]

Comment: This worked for my purposes—as described, this holds the plot to display at the end of the chunk. But for a different use case, is there a solution that doesn't display the plot in the chunk or after the chunk? The goal being to write some text then display the plot.

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer that may get a result closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't fully understand what's happening after the "we will use" line. With each line starting with ``` it looks you're starting multiple chunks.

Comment: Yes, I am starting multiple chunks.  Each one uses the `ref.label` option to reevaluate a chunk, defined elsewhere.  This is how the code is shown at the top, even through the actual R code appears at the end of the .Rmd file.

Comment: Got it. I see now that each of the chunks inside `{r all_code}` displays the r script from chunks that are defined later. The use of  ``` inside of a chunk threw me off.

Answer (score -1):

You can write 2 chunks :

````
## Title

Herebelow the code are not separated by plots :

```{r display_code_only, eval=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
plot(iris)
```

Herebelow the plot are not separated by code :

```{r display_plot_only, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
plot(iris)
```
````

Comment: I tried using  `{r, eval=TRUE, include=FALSE}` but it resulted in hiding all of the text. Plus, using `r plot1` didn't call the plot.

Comment: Thanks Danielle, I updated the 2 chunks options and add exemple.